# Calling google-prettify in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, prettify

I am trying to apply Google Prettify to my AngularJS code but it is working after the ng-route. I also have added a directive for prettify but still facing the problem:

```
app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.html(prettyPrintOne(replaceText(element.html()),'',true));
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the Plunker regarding this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3400Grdp5HejzKuK1sCq?p=preview

Comment: please use your console to check for errors like `app is undefined`. Can't use `onload` for elements that don't exist at run time. Will need to use your pretty code in directive

Comment: Sorry for that I have updated my Plunker